# Joining tables to select data - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables called `students` and `marks`. I have data in these tables like below

**students**

```
id       name
232      James Gordon 
353      Mark Gordon
```

**marks**

```
id     total
232     70
```

In my query below, i am trying to fetch all students who have no marks yet but i am getting all students from the code below. How do i join the table to get this done.

I am newbie to php and mysql. Thank you

**Student Controller**

```
public function getForMarks($class,$session)
{

        $students= Student::selectRaw("regiNo,CAST(rollNo AS SIGNED) as rollNo,firstName,lastName")
            ->where('class','=',$class)
            ->where('section','=',$section)
            ->where('shift','=',$shift)
            ->where('session','=',$session)
            ->orderBy('rollNo','asc')->get();
        return $students;
    }
```

Comment: You should tag the framework. This is a question specific to the framework you are using. I would expect to see a `join` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add to your query

```
 ->whereNOTIn('id',function($query){
               $query->select('id')->from('marks');
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

MySql query to do this is

```
SELECT *
FROM students
INNER JOIN marks ON students.id = marks.id where marks.total is not null ;
```

Comment: No join needed.  `select name from students where id not in (select distinct id from marks)`.  More than one way to skin the cat